# Geocoder's getFromLocationName() always returns one result

Tags: java, android, geocoder

In my code I am trying to display a list of 5 suggested addresses if the user inputs a string in an EditText.

I use

```
List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 5);
```

with searchString being the string that the user entered in the EditText. The results however are always 1 instead of 5. I tried with many city/place names and it only displays to me one suggestion.

I would like to get more than just one result. Can I get help on this?

Comment: You may need to switch to the Places API.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I am programming this task for a company and the Places API has usage limits so it's not gonna be nice. Also, the results format from Geocoder's method are exactly what I need.